# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'popup'

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile-popup

I have been trying to close the jquery popup using $('#partsPopup').popup("close"); But it gave me the no method popup error. This is the order of scripts which i have followed. Please help me. Thanks

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"  />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why do you load `jquery` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to include jQuery once, try to remove the version `1.10.2` here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"  />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```